# If I UPDATE one column in one row in the MySQL InnoDB engine, do I have to wait for the lock to be released when I SELECT another column?

Tags: mysql, innodb, locking

For example, suppose you run the queries below.

```
UPDATE `user`
SET point=30
WHERE id=1;

SELECT nickname
FROM `user`
WHERE id=1;
```

In this case, should the second SELECT query wait for the lock from the UPDATE query even if it doesn't read the point column?

If so, is it a good design to separate the frequently updating column - point - into a separate table user_point?

Comment: A lock locks the whole row, not separate column in this row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

Furthermore, if both statements are in the same transaction, the row lock will continue to be enforced -- this affects *other* threads.

(Non-default transaction isolation modes may act differently.)